# Prometheus service discovery for EC2 application metrics vs EC2 system metrics

Tags: amazon-ec2, prometheus, monitoring, service-discovery

If we install Node Exporter on EC2 instance and run a Java application on the same instance with Java application exposing Prometheus metrics, how do we configure Prometheus to auto-discover both system metrics from Node Exporter and application metrics from Java application? Would they have different service discovery configuration in Prometheus?